# Bounding the number of orthogonal Latin squares from above

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-designs, latin-square, reading-list

As is usual, let $N(n)$ denote the maximum size of a set of mutually orthogonal Latin squares of order $n$. I am wondering what results hold that bound $N(n)$ from above; the only ones I can think of are the following:

1. $N(n)\leq n-1$ for all $n\geq 2$, with equality if $n$ is a prime power. This is well known.
2. $N(6)=1$. This is also quite famous.
3. $N(10)\leq 8$. This was done using a computer search. ([Source](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lam/paper/html/paper.html))
4. If $n=1$ or $2~(mod~4)$, and if $n$ is not a sum of two squares, then $N(n)< n-1$. This is the Bruck-Ryser Theorem from 1949, though stated in Latin squares instead of projective planes.

Are there any other results of this sort? I know of many results bounding $N(n)$ from below (mainly [Beth's result](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02941326) that $N(n)\geq n^{1/14.8}$ if $n$ is large enough, and several results of the form "If $n\geq n_\nu$ then $N(n)\geq \nu$"), but neither I nor anyone I know can add to this list, and I haven't had much luck on Google either.

Answer (score 3):

[Design Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfVh8VaGGeYC) by Beth, Jungnickel & Lenz gives on page 724 the upper bounds

[image]